# Why is my regex not escaping this backslash?

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to create a list of file inside a folder, all matching a regex.
But the regex crash whenever I put a path containing backslash inside the regex.

```
string test = @"C:\TEMP"; // or "C:\\TEMP"
Regex reg = new Regex(test + "\\" + "tstNL02" + @"_(.*).csv"); // it crash here

FileList = Directory.GetFiles(test).Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)).ToList();
```

`ArgumentException: parsing "C:\TEMP\tstNL02_(.*).csv" - Unrecognized escape sequence \T.`

As far as I know, using a @ or escaping the backslash should prevent the regex from interpreting backslashes in a string as an escaping character (and if I remove `test` from the regex but leave the `\\`, regex doesn't crash).

If I put `@"C:\\TEMP"` the Regex doesn't parse any and the match fail `C:\\TEMP\tstNL02_(.*).csv`

I fixed my problem by going another way but I was wondering why and how to fix this backslash-in-a-variable thing ?

Edit: problem didn't came from regex but from the fact I was using the same string for regex and `Directory.GetFiles`. Adding escaping backslashes to the string so Regex worked correctly would cause `Directory.GetFiles` to *not* escape those added backslashes, thus not matching files

Comment: `\T` is not a valid regex escape. You want to double the backslash, `@"\\"`, not `"\\"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\T` is not a valid escape because I don't want it to be one. 
Adding @ before my "\\" doesn't change anything `ArgumentException: parsing "C:\TEMP\\tstNL02_(.*).csv" - Unrecognized escape sequence \T.` Problem is Regex keep interpreting my backslash and if I escape it, it escape both !

Comment: But you should double backlashes everywhere to match literal backslashes, also `@"C:\TEMP"` => `@"C:\\TEMP"`

Comment: It's not the regex that interprets stuff. The pattern is wrong. If you use `\\ ` in a normal literal, it creates a single `\ ` character in the pattern. What you tried created `\t`. If you want to match a backslash you need to escape it *in the pattern itself*. The final string should contain *two* backslashes. That means either using `@"\\"` or `"\\\\"`

Comment: This means you should use `string test = @"C:\\TEMP\\";` and `new Regex(test +  "tstNL02" + @"_(.*).csv")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew all it does it doubling them everything in the result as well `C:\\TEMP\\tstNL02_(.*).csv` and it doesn't match any file.
I should add that the variable 'C:\\Temp" is not mine and is supposed to be retrieved from a server

Comment: It works fine - see [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=C%3a%5c%5cTEMP%5c%5ctstNL02_%28.*%29%5c.csv&i=C%3a%5cTEMP%5ctstNL02_Something.csv) of `Regex reg = new Regex(@"C:\\TEMP\\tstNL02_(.*)\.csv");`

Comment: It seems you do not need a regex here at all: `var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test", "*.csv").Where(p => Path.GetFileName(p).StartsWith("tstNL02_")).ToList();`

Comment: Well I'm stumped. I tried every solution (with regex) you and Panagiotis proposed and none worked (no match found). The solution with no regex worked but I had already found another way which suit me more (`.Where(path => { var real_file = path.Split('\\').Last(); return reg.IsMatch(real_file); })` and `Regex reg = new Regex("tstNL02" + @"_(.*).csv");`)
But I still don't understand why the Regex refuse to work with my path

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I found out why none of your solutions worked .. 
While the string containing my path was correctly escaping (or not) for the Regex, it was also used for the `Directory.GetFiles` which didn't need that much backslash escaping. And for some reason, it was still finding the files but `GetFiles` was adding a backslash in results... Which didn't match with the regex... 

It seem there is no way to use the same string for the regex AND Directory.GetFiles   (unless I heavily parse it every time)

Comment: True, you might probably use `Regex.Unescape(test)` with the `GetFiles` in this concrete example. Or just `.Replace(@"\\", @"\")`

Comment: Both `Unescape` and `GetFiles` worked great :) But since my variable (`test`) is recovered from a server (and I have no control over its value), I'll stick to matching values with only the filename. But I understand why it wasn't working :D Thanks !